# Single Post Template with Dropdown Option?

Tags: templates

I'd like users of my theme to be able to select a single post template via a dropdown menu on the post screen.

I know of [a plugin](http://www.nathanrice.net/plugins/single-post-template/) that achieves this but I would like to be able to achieve the same thing without the plugin.  Anybody have a solution?

Comment: What's wrong with the plugin? It consists of [142 lines of code](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/single-post-template/tags/1.4.3/post_templates.php), seems pretty well coded and does the job. One could simply paste it here and say: "this works". What kind of different solution are you looking for? I can imagine one that would involve a Custom Meta Box, a dropdown with hard-coded template names, and then in `single.php` do a `include("$custom_field.php");`. And at the end, it would be a brand new... plugin.

Answer (score 0):

`

```
        if (is_singular()) {
            $zifana_captain_hook = get_page_template();

            if ($zifana_captain_hook && !preg_match('/page.php$/', $zifana_captain_hook)) {
                include($zifana_captain_hook);
                die();
            }

        }

    }

    // -- Function Name : save_post
    // -- Params : $post_id, $post
    // -- Purpose : 
    function save_post($post_id, $post) {
        $zifana_captain_hook = isset($_POST['zifana_theme_styling'])? $_POST['zifana_theme_styling'] :
        '';

        if ( !empty($zifana_captain_hook) ) {
            $zifana_captain_hooks = get_page_templates();
            $post->page_template = $zifana_captain_hook;

            if ( 'default' != $zifana_captain_hook && !in_array($zifana_captain_hook, $zifana_captain_hooks) ) {
                return;
            }

            update_post_meta($post_id, '_wp_page_template', $zifana_captain_hook);
        }

    }

    // -- Function Name : zifana_hook_theme_metabox
    // -- Params : $post
    // -- Purpose : 
    function zifana_hook_theme_metabox($post) {
        $zifana_captain_hook = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true );
        ?>
```

```
    // -- Function Name : add_dropdown
    // -- Params : 
    // -- Purpose : 
    function add_dropdown() {

        if ( 0 != count( get_page_templates() ) ) {
            add_meta_box('themezifanastyle',__( 'What template huh..', 'zifana'),array(&$this, 'zifana_hook_theme_metabox'),'post');
        }

    }

};
$__zifana_theme_stylings = & new zifanaTemplate;

if (is_admin()) {
    add_action('admin_menu', array(&$__zifana_theme_stylings, 'add_dropdown'));
}

add_action('zifana_page_hook', array(&$__zifana_theme_stylings, 'zifana_page_hook'));
add_action('save_post', array(&$__zifana_theme_stylings, 'save_post'), 10, 2);
```

`
i hope helpfull.. :)

Comment: Please add some explanation to go with your code.